# find and list -R returning different number of files

Tags: grep, find, ls

I'm trying to create an array variable with a list of files to use in a small script, needing the full path to the file. Looking around I tried something like this:

```
find /path/ -t f | grep randomString
```

It turned out that this was returning only some of the files I needed, so I tried using `wc -l` with the previous command and with `ls -R /path/ | grep randomString`, getting different line counts (with a difference of more than 100 lines, so I'm counting the directories from ls -R out). I'm trying to see why `find` is not returning the desired results. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure `ls -R` did not list some symlinks, devices or other special files that you excluded with `-t f` for `find`?

Comment: Good suggestion, but yeah, unfortunately there are no links, devices nor special files in the path listed, only CSV files.

Comment: Please show some sample output (it would have to be the full output from both `find` and `ls -R` for a sample directory). I don't see any evidence here that `find` is omitting entries that `ls -R` shows. `ls -R` has an overhead of about three lines per directory, and you're only claiming to account for one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find` lists all the files in the directory tree. `ls -R` actually lists fewer files: it omits [dot files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory#Unix_and_Unix-like_environments) — you need `ls -AR` to include them.

If you aren't finding the files you need, there are a few possibilities:

- You missed them in the output. Use a search command (e.g. `find … | less` and use the `/` key in less). Keep in mind that the output of `find` is not sorted.
- The files aren't actually called what you think they're called. Do a case-insensitive search if you aren't sure about the case.
- The files you're looking for are actually symbolic links. Use `find -xtype f` instead of `find -type f` to categorize symbolic links as the file they point to.
- The files are under a symbolic link to a directory. Use `find -L` to traverse symbolic links, but be careful: this could search a very large number of files if you have a symbolic link to a directory that's at the top of a large hierarchy.

In no case would `ls -R` find files that `find` doesn't.

You can't easily compare the number of lines in output of `ls -R` and `find`:

- `ls -R` omits dot files, `find` doesn't.
- `ls -R` has a total of three extra lines for each subdirectory (except for the root), compared with `find -type f`: the directory entry, the blank line that separates the listing of that directory from the previous line, and the header line with the directory name followed by a colon.

Comment: `find -xtype f` instead `find -type f` seems to work as I was expecting, though I'm almost sure that there were no symbolic links within the directories. Now that I have located the problem I can finally keep working on the script. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

When you execute ls -R you get as output the directories names in the listing.

Comment: True, I should have specified that the difference in the line count is too big and the results completely different when I don't pipe the commands through `wc -l`

Comment: Check also if ls do not return the results in one line and you grep one occurrence from several

Comment: Checked, both commands return results in several lines when being piped through grep.